# How do I download packages manually and install them then?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro, deb

I want to do this without internet connection, as I go where I don't have internet?

For arch-based what's the command to download and after that how do I install packages from terminal?

How to write a script to automate installation?

I also cannot change my backlight in manjaro, as backlight files not found running legacy bios, but in laptop it changes using fn key, although in manjaro I don't have backlights files there too. I want to do this without any utility, I know files are located somewhere else as the fn key works!!

Comment: also how to store updates, so install the same without downloading 700MB of manjaro updates again? and the same for arch?

Comment: tell the procedure for debian-based distros like ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 2):

Debian-Ubuntu based distros:

```
# aptitude -d download 'package'
```

Download in actual directory

Arch based distros:

```
# pacman -Sw 'package'
```

Download in /var/cache/pacman/pkg/

More information, use `man [command]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't download the .deb and install it manually with dependencies ? (and for updates, you can check on the web on how you can do that for a specified package)

Debian/Ubuntu to install a .deb :

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

And you can write a script to automate the installation with your .deb files.

Comment: how to install for arch-based distros and download, actually i use debian i.e. ubuntu very less, but after download how to install it, never tried what's the COMMAND TO INSTALL?

Comment: You download all files before and you package it in a tar. Your script will extract the tar => Get the arch => Build the command to install the good package => Launch the command. The command to install a package is on my above message. And if you need, the script can have an auto remove of itself. If you want more informations for the installation, you can go on the next link => http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line

Comment: ya, but u never told me the command to JUST DOWNLOAD a package first, in neither ubuntu nor arch?

Comment: Ha sorry, I didn't understand the question. You can use the command "wget [URL]" to download something on Unix system (include Ubuntu). If the command "wget" don't work on your system ,you can install the package "wget" with aptitude ("apt-get install wget" or "aptitude install wget")

Comment: i mean without the URL bro, like for any package from the terminal. `apt-get source [package]` gives the source without really going to the URL. it is quick and efficient. if it install the package, i presume that it ATLEAST has access to the package(in the background), because without it, it just couldn't install. i hope now you got the question.